# How to keep last created state when there is recursive state change in state machine?

Tags: c++, state-machine

I have a state machine like code, which has state A,B and C, and a function changeState(char i) which can change the state of a system, and each state can call changeState(char i) to switch the system to another state:

```
struct State{
    State(char aName){
        this->name=aName;
    }
    char name;
};

void changeState(char i);

struct A : public State{
    A():State('A'){
        changeState('B');
    }
};

struct B : public State{
    B():State('B'){
        changeState('C');
    }
};

struct C : public State{
    C():State('C'){
    }
};

State* state;
void changeState(char i){
    switch(i){
        case 'A':
            state=new A();
            break;
        case 'B':
            state=new B();
            break;
        case 'C':
            state=new C();
            break;
    }
}
```

Now I want to trigger state change, start from A to C:

```
int main(){
    changeState('A');
    printf("%c\n",state->name);
    return 0;
}
```

the flow is : changeState('A')->new A()->changeState('B')->new B()->changeState(C)->new C(), I want the last state be C, but now is A, how can I modify changeState(char i) to do that? I try using a list to hold all temp state object:

```
std::list<State*> stateList;
void changeState(char i){
    switch(i){
        case 'A':
            stateList.push_front(new A());
            break;
        case 'B':
            stateList.push_front(new B());
            break;
        case 'C':
            stateList.push_front(new C());
            break;
    }
    stateList.pop_back();
}

int main(){
    stateList.push_front(new State('s'));
    changeState('A');
    printf("%lu %c\n",stateList.size(),stateList.back()->name);
    return 0;
}
```

but the last state is still A instead of C, how do I modify changeState(char i) ?

Comment: On an unrelated note, I hope this isn't your actual code, or you would have a lot of memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Lets break down the initial call using `changeState('A')` into the operations that happens:

1. You call `changeState('A')
2. You do `new A()`
3. Which calls the `A` constructor which calls `changeState('B')`
4. Which does `new B()`
5. The `B` constructor calls `changeState('C')`
6. Which does `new C()`
7. And the new `C` object is assigned to the pointer `state`
8. `changeState` returns, going back to the `B` constructor
9. The `B` constructor returns, which puts control back in the `changeState('B')` call
10. The assignment of `state = new B()` is performed
11. The `changeState` function returns to the `A` constructor
12. The `A` constructor returns to the `changeState('A')` call
13. The `state = new A()` assignment is made
14. The `changeState` function returns to the `main` function
15. The `state` variable now points to an `A` object

The simplest solution? Don't call `changeState` in the constructors!

---

As for the other example with the list, remember that the list starts out empty. Then when you call `changeState` you add a node, then you immediately remove the same node you just added.